# Google Calendar notifications not working

Tags: notifications, google-calendar

I loved how I got SMS messages from Google Calendar.

Then they removed that, I installed the Mobile App, but I get no notifications. How can I get notifications from Google Calendar Mobile App? Is there a checklist of what do I need to check to have notifications?

I have:

- Samsung Galaxy S3
- Android 4.4.2.
- Google Calendar app up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To built the comments below cOmrad answer : you can also create default notification for each calendar (group of events)(the default group is simply "Event").

1. open calendar
2. select menu (top left)
3. scroll down to settings
4. under your email select your calendar (click on show more if you have more than one otherwise select "Event")
5. choose a default color and notifications.

Each of your email/ "calendar" can have its own defauls color/notifications.

This will only be a template, you will still be able to set the color and  nofications when you create/edit a particular event.

Answer (score 2):

You can set notification type and time while you are creating event or you also able to modify already created events:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Oh, I think I found it. Ouch. It Hurts. I will have to do this for every event in my calendar ? Separately?

Comment: Well, if you need to customize a specific notification time or date then it's obvious that yes, you should set notifications one by one assuming that they are different events, if not each event has "10 minutes before" notification set by default so you won't miss it anyway.

Comment: By the way, one more thing if you will edit event which **repeats** in future, after editing there will be pup up alert asking you if you would like to affect future(the same events which repeats) events as well, so you won't have to do the same event editing separately.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 (adapt for android). To resolve (for me) Google calendar no notification issue I found that if you activate google calendar extension in chrome => more tools => 
extensions then click on calendar tool in top right toolbar then select a calendar entry it will ask you to logon. Logon. Then you should be able to receive notifications. I hope it works for you as well :)

Comment: Sharing your experience getting notifications working is great, but I don't think your Windows instructions are relevant to Android users.